# Hibernate Validator And Joda DateTime Validator

Tags: spring, hibernate, jodatime, thymeleaf

I have a **User** model class with a Joda DateTime field and following validation rules:

```
@NotEmpty
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
@Past
private DateTime dob;
```

Once I submit my registration form I get this error:

```
No validator could be found for type: org.joda.time.DateTime.
```

How can I add a validator to this field?

Comment: silly question but do you have "import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;" in that class somewhere?

Comment: I am using org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat

Comment: Swap it around for the one i have listed

Comment: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat is not an annotation

Comment: Yep you are right, i realised i had misread. Let me give it another shot. How aer you doing your validation?  Can you show the code for your method and validation.

Comment: Validation is done by Hibernate Validator by simply adding "@NotEmpty" and "@Past"

Answer (score 0):

Using `@NotNull` instead of `@NotEmpty` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own validator to use with Joda's `DateTime`.

`@Past` will only work with (non-Joda) `Date` and `Calendar`.  I am not aware of a library that provides Java bean validators for Joda types.

FYI, the Javadoc for `@Past` states which types it supports:

```
/**
 * The annotated element must be a date in the past.
 * Now is defined as the current time according to the virtual machine.
 * <p/>
 * The calendar used if the compared type is of type {@code Calendar}
 * is the calendar based on the current timezone and the current locale.
 * <p/>
 * Supported types are:
 * <ul>
 *     <li>{@code java.util.Date}</li>
 *     <li>{@code java.util.Calendar}</li>
 * </ul>
 * <p/>
 * {@code null} elements are considered valid.
 *
 * @author Emmanuel Bernard
 */
```